# wpf mvvmlight passing data to viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have the following views and viewModels View: Staff, VM: StaffViewModel and View: Notes, VM: NotesViewModel.

My StaffViewModel has a SelectedStaffMember property of type SelectedEmployee.

The Staff view has a button that launches another view (Notes).

When the user enters a note I need to save it against the SelectedEmployee, which means the NotesViewModel needs to know the currently selected employee ID.

Right now Im doing this via my ViewModelLocator but this seems wrong, what is the corret way to pass data to a VM???

I'm using MVVM Light.

Relevant code - StaffViewModel

```
public Employee SelectedEmployee
    {
        get { return _selectedEmployee; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _selectedEmployee) return;
            _selectedEmployee = value;
            HolidayAllowance = _staffDataService.GetEmployeeHolidayAllowance(_selectedEmployee.Id);
            RaisePropertyChanged();
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(HolidayAllowance));
        }
    }
```

NoteViewModel

```
public RelayCommand SaveNoteCommand { get; private set; }

private void SaveNote()
{
   var note = new Note
   {
      NoteContent = NoteContent,
      EmployeeId =  ViewModelLocator.Staff.SelectedEmployee.Id,
      NoteDate = NoteDate
   };

   _dataService.SaveNote(note);
}
```

I'm using MahApps Flyouts to show the view for add note:
This is where the view is shown, it is launched from MainView.xaml NOT Staff.xaml, which I think is going to be another issue of getting SelectedEmployee ID:

MainView.xaml

```
<controls:Flyout Name="AddNoteFlyout"
                Header="Add Note" 
                IsModal="True"
                IsOpen="{Binding IsAddNoteOpen}"
                Opacity="85" 
                Position="Right" 
                Width="450">
                <views:AddNote VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,30,0,0"/>
</controls:Flyout>
```

Im considering firing a message on the button click that launches the View, which my staff view would register against. The message would contain the selectedEmployeeId. Would that be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The simple way**

The simple way is what you are doing, but maybe a bit better solution is to create a `static` or `singleton` class like a `NavigationParameterContainer` and store the selected `StaffMember` in a public property. Then you can retrieve it in your `NotesViewModel`

**The best practice**

The better solution for passing data between `ViewModels` is using a custom navigation service, and navigation aware `ViewModels`.

MVVMLight don't support this, so either you use a different framework like Prism or write yourself an architecture that you can use for making parameterized navigationt.

The base idea is that you create an `INavigationAware` interface that support navigation lifecycle callbacks like `OnNavigatedTo`, which receives an object representing the `NavigationParamter` (the selected StaffMember).

Then you create some kind of `NavigationService` with a `Navigate` method, that accepts some parameter to determine the `Page` you want to navigate to, and an `object` wich is the `NavigationParamter`.

When you navigate you call the `Navigate` method on your Service and pass the selected item as parameter. Then you need to make the actual navigation inside your service, and after the navigation is finished, you call the `OnNavigatedTo` callback on your `ViewModel` if it is implementing the `INavigationAware` interface. (You can retreive the VM from the `Page.DataContext` and cast it to `INavigationAware` if it is not null you can call the `OnNavigatedTo`).

Finally in your NotesViewModel you just need to implement the `INavigationAware` interface, and handle the parameter you received in the `OnNavigatedTo` method.

This is just the basic idea but I strongly recommend you to see some MVVM framework that already implements this. (like [PrismLibrary](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism)).